# Lenses for MVC framework in Haskell

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, haskell

I've been mulling around the idea of how you'd construct a MVC framework in Haskell in the mold of WPF or AngularJS, but can't seem to find the key types or idea to get started. So unfortunately vague question - has anyone else out there been thinking about this problem?

I see edit-lenses, multi-plate and Compos, but I think they all solve slightly different problems.

My rough sketch of how that would work would be:

1. Create a model as a plain haskell data structure
2. Create a set of 'lenses' or commands to modify your model.
3. Write a HTML (or whatever) template which is parametised by the types in the model.

.

```
data Model = Page { _title :: String, _content :: [(Int, String)] }

title :: Lens Model String
content :: Int -> Lens Model (Maybe String)
```

Then I would want to be able to write a function:

```
Model -> Template Model -> Html
```

and a function to update parts of my view when I apply a lens.

```
Lens Model a -> a -> HtmlTemplate Model -> [(Path, Html)]
```

So I guess the question is - what type would a lens take which can operate on one data structure, then be used to describe the change in another.

One possibility seems to be to create a GADT which wraps all the lenses and then template the HTML over the GADT type which can then be used to match against the template at each step. e.g.

```
data Lenses a b where
    Title :: Lens Model String -> Lenses Model String
    Item  :: Lens Model String -> Lenses Model (Maybe String)
```

Then a Html Template data type e.g.

```
data HtmlTemplate a = Text String 
              | Element String [Attrib a] 
              | forall b. Binding (Lenses a b) (Html b)
```

To which the Binding element can be pattern matched against directly.

But that seems almost defeating the point, because the model is then joined at the hip to the view.

I wonder has anyone (smarter than I) out there put thought into how this might work? Or even if this is a good idea?

Comment: I've started an experimental lens library meant to support arbitrary effectful operations, which you might be interested in looking at (can't recommend you use it at the moment as the API will be changing, it's experimental, and was roundly shat upon when it was discussed on reddit). the closest to your case would be the last example in [this post](http://brandon.si/code/yall/); you'd probably want your view to be modified in `State` when you do lens ops on the model: `LensM (State View) Model a` or something like that. but I haven't used the MVC pattern much, so forgive me if I'm off

Comment: I think that is at least half of the solution, so that you can either build up your changes to a view (or modify the view directly). However I think what I'm missing is a mechanism to traverse the model and the view (templated model) together - some kind of zip to traverse the two related structures at the same time.

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/04/model-view-controller-haskell-style.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been building a large commercial application using lens-based "MVC" in Haskell.

- Purely functional data structures
- Lenses for setting and getting (and keeping the data consistent)
- A DSL for generating a view (template) tied to each lens.

This has been a great experience, and I definitely recommend the approach for detailed structure editing of complex structures.

The approach forces you to

- Not hack, but use lenses as safe interfaces to your internal model
- Strong separation of the model -> view
- Type checking for everything -- lens types to generate view code

There's lots of ways you can design it, but I think it is a very sound design approach. You will want good DSL support for the GUI part.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "A DSL for generating a view (template) tied to each lens."? sounds tres cool.

Comment: Basically, a template language that associates a typed control on the screen with its corresponding lens. So buttons, text input, numerical input etc can be linked to the editing lens for that input, and graphs of such lenses can be wired up. The UI then just falls out.

Comment: Sounds nice. I want to do local web apps using Html as a UI using a similar method. (Or with UHC Javascript some day). Cheers :)

Comment: @Oliver sounds a lot like formlets